# When to unsubscribe from `route.params` observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I don't know the scenarios where I should unsubscribe from `route.params` observable.

- Angular docs says we don't need to unsubscribe.

So what is the use cases where I should unsubscribe?

Comment: why do you want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51732897/8286262), you should not subscribe except for being a dynamic or a child component:

> Unsubscribe from the ActivatedRoute observables like route.params if
>   they are subscribed inside a nested (Added inside tpl with the
>   component selector) or dynamic component as they may be subscribed
>   many times as long as the parent/host component exists. No need to
>   unsubscribe from them in other scenarios as mentioned in the quote
>   above from Routing & Navigation docs.

Comment: I edited your answer I think you mean `unsubscribe` not `subscribe`

Comment: @WaleMax Sorry, my bad. Thanks